# unix script problem

Tags: unix, shell, sed

I have a simple script which runs on a FreeBSD machine with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
`sed -i .bak '\:#start 172.0.0.3:,\:#end 172.0.0.3:d' /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`
echo $?
```

It should delete a block of text between the two patterns.

The problem is that if I run the sed command directly from shell it works, if i run the script the return code is 0.

Why's that?

Comment: the command is `sed -i .bak '\:#start 172.0.0.3:,\:#end 172.0.0.3:d' /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`, between `` so it can be executed within the shell script

Comment: From the phrasing of your question, it seems like you weren't expecting a return value of 0 for a successfully executed command, when this is precisely the behavior a command should exhibit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to eliminate the backticks and change the single quotes to double quotes:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=$1
echo $ip
sed -i .bak "\:#start ${ip}:,\:#end ${ip}:d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf
```

Using double quotes will allow the variables to be expanded. The backticks would try to execute the standard output of the command (which there is none in this case). For example, if you did `` `echo hi` `` it would try to execute "hi" as a command. `sed` always returns 0 unless there's an error regardless of whether a replacement was made.

Comment: thanks!worked. however if we are here i want to ask you something else (since this was a sub-problem of my big problem).

I have a script called rootexec.sh which contains the code :

#!/bin/sh
exec $1

(this script is used as a parameter for a sudo). The problem is that 
if i use script.sh 'sed -i .bak "\:#start 172.0.0.3:,\:#end 172.0.0.3:d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'

(the sed being the $1 parameter for the exec command), i get this error : sed: 1: ""\:#start": invalid command code " . exec seems to have a problem with it?

Comment: should i post this as a separate problem?

Comment: @Darie: There's a serious security risk of passing commands as parameters to scripts that get run using `sudo`. That said, you might try putting double quotes round `$1`: `exec "$1"`. Also read [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: with "$1" i get this error : exec: sed -i .bak "\:#start 172.0.0.2:,\:#end 172.0.0.2:d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf: not found

I am working on a system build by somebody else and i need to use their scripts.

Comment: @Darie: The next thing I would suggest trying is, instead of the double quotes, escape the backslashes or use forward slashes: `script.sh 'sed -i .bak "\\:#start 172.0.0.3:,\\:#end 172.0.0.3:d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'` or `script.sh 'sed -i .bak "/#start 172.0.0.3/,/#end 172.0.0.3/d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'`

Comment: tried both ways and i get the same thing exec: sed -i .bak "/#start 172.0.0.2/,/#end 172.0.0.2/d" /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf: not found

Comment: ive tried smth simple like : /usr/local/www/rootexec.sh 'echo lala > /tmp/lala' and i get the same thing : exec: echo lala > /tmp/lala: not found

the command not found problem is because of "$1" thingie

Comment: @Darie: Did you try the `$1` without the `""`? Did you read the FAQ that I linked to?

Comment: Without "" for sed i get : sed: 1: ""\:#start": invalid command code "
(the error i posted before). For echo however i get : cat: /tmp/lala: No such file or directory
BOX# /usr/local/www/rootexec.sh 'echo lala > /tmp>lala'
lala > /tmp>lala
BOX#

It doesnt show any error but the /tmp/lala file doesnt get created.
I've looked over the FAQ but i don't see anything that can help me ?

Comment: @Darie: "i don't see anything that can help me" - That's the point of that FAQ: "Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Doctor: Don't do that."

Comment: I dont see that point, you sure the link is ok?

Comment: @Darie: It's peppered with "doesn't work", "don't do that", etc. However, try this: `script.sh 'sed -i .bak \:#start 172.0.0.3:,\:#end 172.0.0.3:d /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'` or, with variables: `script.sh 'sed -i .bak \:#start '${ip}':,\:#end '${ip}':d /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'`

Comment: BOX# /usr/local/www/rootexec.sh 'sed -i .bak \:#start 172.0.0.3:,\:#end 172.0.0.3:d /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf'
sed: 1: "\:#start": unterminated regular expression

Nope.. seems its not working :(

Comment: @Darie: I'm running out of ideas. It could be a difference in the BSD dialect of `sed` versus the GNU version. One more thing to try: Change the `$1` in `rootexec.sh` to `$@` and try it with some of the variations we've gone through for specifying the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

The backticks really are not necessary (or perhaps I understand you wrong). The fact that the script returns 0 is also expected: exit code 0 is OK. Edit: sed will always exit with 0, even if there has been no substitution. Another exit code is only then generated when there is an error in your syntax.

More interesting is: is the code deleted or not?

Judging from your comments, you probably have a problem with regexp and / or escaping characters in it.

Comment: actually the script is using a parameter (the ip)

#!/bin/sh

ip=$1 
echo $ip
`sed -i .bak '\:#start ${ip}:,\:#end ${ip}:d' /usr/local/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`
echo $?

The text block doesnt get deleted from the file even if the return code is OK.

Comment: the .bak file is created (that means the command was executed, however the block of code was not removed)